# Will the real vertical bars (in Sh'ma) please stand up?

Tags: shema, trop-cantillation, artscroll

I use the ArtScroll *sidurim* (prayer books), which include a great many vertical bars between adjacent words of the three paragraphs of "*Sh'ma*", wherever the editors felt people may come to slur adjacent words together. Unfortunately, these vertical bars look exactly like the vertical bars used as cantillation marks. Thus, although the *sidurim* include cantillation marks, any *p'sik* (or *pasek*) or *munach l'garmeh* is lost among the plethora of vertical bars thrown in by the ArtScroll editors. Is there any such *p'sik* or *munach l'garmeh* in "*Sh'ma*", and, if so, where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only such 'real' (cantillation) vertical bar in the three paragraphs of "*Sh'ma*" appears before the word "*echad*" in the first *pasuk*. (It represents a *p'sik*.) (Source: two good-quality *chumashim*.)

Comment: This agrees with the pointing in the Keter Yerushalayim, ArtScroll, and Koren Tanachs, as well as every tikkun I've seen. In my opinion, the editors of the ArtScroll siddur went a little overboard with guiding the reader on correct phrasing. It's particularly noticeable in opening pasuk of the Shema, where (in my edition) they have managed to indicate a pause between every word (either a comma or a pasek).

Comment: I speculate this is to avoid eliding the Alef in Echad and running the consonental Yud of Adonay into the next word to get Yachad, which would sound awfully Christian in context.